# how to remove "#" from the color code using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove "#" character from the color code using RegEx in javascript. I tried one, but my script is not working... please some body take a look and correct my code.

```
<html>
    <script>
      var input = "#a478ff";
      var color = input.match(/([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9])\b*/gi);
      alert(color);
    </script>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you know it's there, why not just use substring?  Or, are you trying to catch cases when it may not exist?  I guess I don't really see why you need RegEx for this.

Answer (score 7):

RegEx is unnecessary for this, just use `replace()`:

```
var input = "#a478ff";
var color = input.replace('#','');
```

Or you could use substring:

```
var input = "#a478ff";
var color = input.substring(1);
```

For those cases where the `#` may not be present, the `replace()` approach is more reliable, as the `substring()` will *always* 'remove' the first character; whereas the `replace()` will replace only what it finds.

Comment: I prefer `.slice()` four character less ;-)

Answer (score 2):

But if you really want a regexp, here's the correct one:

```
var color = input.match(/[A-F0-9]*\b/i);
if (color) { alert(color[0]) };
```

Comment: Out of curiosity how would you specify that it must match a string of either 3 or 6 characters? I know how to specify a range (`{3,6}`), but not the 3-or-6 only. =/

Comment: Why not, if the input is "#123456789"? He just wants to get past the '#'.

Comment: Because it's not a valid hexadecimal color-code (admittedly that doesn't form part of the question, but even so, it's fairly important, I think?)

Comment: `/\b((?:[a-f0-9]{3}){1,2})\b/` will match 3 or 6 hex digits